# How to remap xinput inputs to other keys?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, xinput, tablet

I'm on Mint 18.1 Serena 64-bit with cinnamon.

I want to remap my graphic tablet's pen's keys. the tablet GUI in system setting won't detect the tablet (Which is a genius i608X). but it actually works.

Xinput detects the tablet and it's keys being pressed. the problem is their default behavior isn't any good. so I need a way (or tool) to remap these keys to something like ctrl+z instead of right click. every tool I saw works specifically for mouse/keyboard keys. So they couldn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `xbindkeys` to detect and remap the key event to call `xdotool`?

With a button id of 123 your `~/.xbindkeysrc` should contain something like

```
"xdotool key ctrl+z"
  b:123
```

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys
You can actually use `xbindkeys` to trigger any command you like.

Remember that you need to restart `xbindkeys` for the changes to take effect:

```
pkill xbindkeys && xbindkeys
```

To find out the button id / keycode use `xev`

Comment: thanks. I didn't know xbindkeys can work with raw input too. just some clarifications for others: I needed to remap my buttons with "xinput set-button-map [tablet-id] 1 27 3 4 5 6 7 then add the command in the answer with b:27 in second line.

Comment: You're welcome! I spent a couple of hours to get my own mouse to work and ended up with a solution using raw input, a moment later I saw your question. Hence good timing ;)